# Automatically apply a custom sql-function on a property inside an entity

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I am using symfony with doctrine and I'm trying to automatically apply a custom sql-function on a property inside an entity.

I've already defined the custom sql-function in `dql` service and I can use it custom functions I've made in the entity repository..

```
orm:
    mappings:
      AppBundle:
        type: annotation
    dql:
      string_functions:
        translate_term: AppBundle\DoctrineExtensions\Utils\TranslateTerm
```

The thing is I want to be able to use `findAll()` for simple queries.

I was thinking to use `AbstractIdGenerator` but I'm not really sure if it'll help me because to my understanding its for insert. while what I want is to translate data received from db.

```
   /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="mi_term", type="string", length=25, nullable=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="AppBundle\DoctrineExtensions\Utils\TranslateTermEntity")
     */
    private $miTerm;
```

The purpose is translating db term on query.

Any insights will be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is impossible, and for a good reason.

As it was mentioned to me by one of the dev team it is generally a bad idea to handle this on db (though there is an implementation of entity translation via listener).

Link to his answer and existing implementation
https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6269#issuecomment-276399555

For rounding a property value (which might be more common use) you can use `scale` property in `@Column()` Annotation.

Since I totally agree with his comment I'll probably prepare a language pack to the client and attach it to client translation solution.